# Calculate limit with $\sqrt{2}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Please help mi with:
 $$ \lim_{n \rightarrow  \infty } ( \sqrt{2}- \sqrt[3]{2}  )( \sqrt{2}- \sqrt[5]{2}  ) \ldots ( \sqrt{2}- \sqrt[2n+1]{2}  ) $$

Comment: Thank you. That was really helpful.